# PDO: Create dynamic insert syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a project that requires me to do a database insert with quite some columns to fill. I tried making my function dynamic so that I didn't have to type 28 insert into- columns, 28 placeholders, and then bind 28 values to 28 placeholders....and in the near future I might want to add more columns, so here's how I tried to set it up, the whole function and arrays are a bit to much to post here so I'll stick to the essential part with some psuedo code for my question:

-In my form, there are up to 28 inputs, and the input names are the same as the database column name
-The essential part of my code is as follows (some replaced by pseudo code to shorten this post)

```
    <?php 
    //stacks holds 28 values in total
    $stacks = array('name1','name2','name3','blablabla','etcetera');

    // stacksDP is filled in a loop, 
    //contains the same as $stacks but it has a : 
    //in front of every value. 
    $stacksDP = array() // :name1',':name2', ....

    $data = array(); // $data[stack / columnname] = "whatever";

    $execArray = array();
    //$execArray is filled like this in a foreach loop on $stacks as $stack: 
    //$execArray[$stacksDP[$stack]] = $data[$stack];

// so far so good, but now I want to make the actual query and the following gives me a "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;  "
        $sql = "INSERT INTO stackoverflowplaceholder (".implode("','",$stacks)." VALUES (";
        $sql .= implode(",",$stacksDP); // :columnname,
        $sql .=")";
        $q = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        echo $q->execute($execArray);
```

Any help on this matter would be appreciated :) Is it even possible what I'm trying to achieve here?

Comment: Echo the `$sql`. Do you have an extra comma for the column assignment, reserved word, etc.?

Comment: I think your issue is in your loop with `$execArray[$stacksDP[$stack]] = $data[$stack];`. Instead of `foreach($stacks as $stack)`, you probably want to do `foreach($stacks as $key => $stack)` and then ` `$execArray[$stacksDP[$stack]] = $data[$stack];` should be `$execArray[$stacksDP[$key] = $data[$stack];`. As `$stacksDP[$stack]`, ie. `$stacksDP['name1']` would not exist.

Comment: @chris85 I did....and I didn't notice at first but after playing a game and looking again I saw it...I forgot to add a ) after imploding the column names ! Feel free to copy that line, put the ) there and post it as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it and upvote ;)

Comment: Answer added. I find outputting the query is a useful debugging technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing, `)`, to close the column assignment, before the implode.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO stackoverflowplaceholder (".implode("','",$stacks)." VALUES (";
```

will be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO stackoverflowplaceholder (".implode("','",$stacks)."  ) VALUES (";
```